# arabic language issue in mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

when insert text with number in mysql useing arabic language showing problem in   Reverse text and number for example assuming you arabic characters :

1 kg  after insert  become kg 1
**Notes:** I am set collection for table mysql utf8

can anyone help me Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this happen only when you enter values in Arabic? Are you manually inserting values into database via phpmyadmin?

Comment: yes this happen only enter values in arabic and i am try many method to add value same issue

Comment: What is the data type of the column? Are you displaying the data in phpMyAdmin or your own application?

Comment: type data varchar and i display data in phpmyadmin and in xml file same problem but can solve problem in xml  with set dir=rtl but can't make this in xml file